# Correct answer before return, incorrect after return

Tags: c

I've been Googling this for hours, but with no luck.

I'm using standard c, calling a very simple method, and returning the correct value, but after the return the value is completely wrong.

call:

```
     //declare the gross and ficaTax variables
    double gross;
    double ficaTax;

    //calculate the gross and the ficaTax
    gross = calcGross(payRate, hours); printf("%f\n", gross); //DELETE
```

Method:

```
double calcGross(double rate, double hours){

    double gross;

    //if the person didn't work more than 40 hours  
    if(hours <= 40.0){
            gross = hours * rate;
    }

    //if the person did work more than 40 hours
    else{
            gross = 40.0 * rate + ((hours - 40.0) * rate * 1.5);
    }

    printf("%f \t", gross);
    return gross;
}
```

I'm printing out the values in and out of the method to try and solve it, but I can't figure it out. Here is the output:

(correct)        (incorrect, after return)

529.600000 ,     -858993459.000000

1371.522500   ,    171798692.000000

100.000000   , 0.000000

1515.710000  ,     171798692.000000

977.255000   , 1030792150.000000

5631.360000  ,     687194767.000000

7502.400000  ,     1717986918.000000

4335.106000  ,     584115553.000000

1924.181500 ,      -618475291.000000

683.084000  ,  137438953.000000

1348.424000    ,  755914245.000000

1369.200000  ,     -858993460.000000

529.600000   , -858993459.000000

4441.522500  ,     -1030792152.000000

100.000000  ,  0.000000

1882.710000  ,     171798692.000000

My only guesses were either that my double post-return was too long to fit in the length of a double, but I stored it in a double pre-return and it printed correctly. If this is the case I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
My other guess was that I'm printing it out wrong post-return, but I am printing it the same way.

I'm using Linux and with the gcc compiler if that matters. Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to fix this seemingly simple problem for hours.

Comment: Does the compiler issue any warnings? Did you provide a prototype for the function before the call?

Comment: Are you certain you're giving us the code exactly as you use it? There's no chance that you're misspelling the variable name that you're printing out, or declaring a new `gross` between the function call and the `printf()`?

Comment: Did you declare calcGross before the call or after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't given a declaration or prototype for the `calcgross()` function before it's being called in your first example.

Without having seen a declaration/prototype for the function the C compiler will assume that it's returning an `int`, not `double`, so things go terribly wrong.

Place the following line somewhere before you call the function (ideally in a header that you include):

```
double calcGross(double rate, double hours);
```

Using the `-Wall` compiler option would give you the following warning about this:

```
test.c:73:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'calcGross' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll add -Wall to my compile script.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely problem is that you have not declared `calcGross` prior to using it, in which case the compiler would assume default return type (`int`). Try placing the `calcGross()` definition before using it.

Answer (score -1):

Silly, subtle error.  Use "printf ("%lf", gross)" in both places and I'll bet the problem goes away :)

Comment: `%f` should be the same `%lf` for `printf()` since `float` is promoted to `double` when it appears in a varargs list. It's important for `scanf()` because you're passing pointers.

Comment: I doubt it. C promotes floats to doubles for functions that take variable arguments, `printf("%f")` should work just fine, as corroborated by the first value being printed out correctly.

Comment: I'm sure that's the exact code and the names are correct. %lf was one of my first attempts at a fix, but it gives the exact same output. I can post the entire code if needed.