# Functions not returning correct value in DLL

Tags: c, windows, gcc, dll, return

This is so frustrating! I don't know why this is happening. I have a file called **weirdDLL.c**:

```
double five() {
    return 5.0;
}
```

I have another file called **weirdTest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double f = five();
    if (f != 5.0) {
        printf("Test failed with %f", f);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that, when compiled and linked with the DLL, the code in weirdTest will exit without error. I am compiling on **64bit Windows 7** using **gcc (cygwin)** with the commands:

```
gcc -c weirdDLL.c
gcc -shared -o weirdDLL.dll weirdDLL.o
gcc -o test weirdtest.c -L./ -l weirdDLL
./test
```

The output is:

```
Test failed with 0.000000
```

It seems like the DLL is getting linked up correctly because the compiler does not complain about missing function "five." Additionally, when I put print statements in the DLL code, they show up fine. What did I do wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780930/correct-answer-before-return-incorrect-after-return You have the same problem - you need to have a declaration/prototype for function `five()` before `main()` calls it so the compiler knows it doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Yes was the issue, thanks! The DLL was a red herring. But why does the compiler expect an int? The function prototype is available in the DLL code and I'm also assigning the return value to a double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a wild guess:

You don't seem to declare a prototype for five() in weirdTest.c, this is why the compiler treats the return type of that function as int. The resulting conversion from int to double messes up your original double value.

Comment: Your wild guess seems to be correct :) But @Michael was _just_ faster than you. Nevertheless, +1!

Comment: Unfortunately Michael posted his answer as a comment so I'll mark this one correct. Thanks!

Comment: I think the moral of this story is that when stuff goes wrong you should look at the compiler's warnings and fix them. The warnings are there for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

use dumpbin(windwos) or nm(linux) to list your export function from the DLL

and see whether five() is exported or not